# How to make banner for the Android App which could fit all sizes of mobile screens

Tags: android, android-layout, banner

I wanted to make the banner for my application. But the size of the android mobiles screens may vary in width. Is there any way that I can make auto resizable image which can be scaled by the size without any distortion.

Comment: Have you read the docs? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: It's not clear to tell what you do really want to do, it's not clear either to tell wether or not you've at least googled your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 9 patch image. It will stretch only part of your image, keeping the business area intact. Look at this [link](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2010/06/9-patches/) to know more how to create such images. Do make sure you make hdpi, mdpi, ldpi, xhdpi versions of these 9 patch images, so you will be able to support all screens sizes.

Answer (score 0):

easy and gives best results using 9patch images....[to create the 9patch images look this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=RoCDFQnWrt8)